# javascript onClick update user_meta from jquery.ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript, jquery

The idea is to add two values and the total of the sum save it or update it in user_meta with jquery.ajax.
This is the code, but it gives me an error in the console Uncaught ReferenceError: 'total' is not defined

Please, Any help is appreciated!

**My Button**

```
<a href="" onclick="CounterTrav()" id="btnTraPack"></a>
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
//This sum the tow values i get from a click and works OK!

const clicksContainer = document.querySelector('.clicksContainer');
const totalEl = document.createElement('span');
clicksContainer.appendChild(totalEl);

clicksContainer.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('clicksContainer')) {
    const shareCLick = document.querySelectorAll('.resultTraveler');
    let total = 0;
    shareCLick.forEach(item => {
      total += parseInt(item.innerText, 10)
    totalEl.innerHTML = total
    })
    console.log(total);
  }
})

var clickCounterTrav = 0
function CounterTrav() {
    
  clickCounterTrav += 1;
  document.getElementById("resultTraveler").innerHTML = clickCounterTrav + " Travel Pack you have Shared!";
console.log(clickCounterTrav);

var CounterTrav_update = 'clickCounterTrav';
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        
        data : {
            action : 'CounterTrav_update', 
            CounterTrav_value : CounterTrav_value,
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
               console.log('Updating Field');
        },
        success : function( response ) {
             console.log('Success');
        },
        
    });
}
</script>
```

> // MY ISSUE START HERE
> If I use

```
var CounterTrav_update = 'clickCounterTrav';
```

The result of the sum is Correct, and the user_meta is Update OK!, **BUT** only update "clickCounterTrav"
Like Eg: The user onready have in user_meta 2 clicks storage, and in session2 click just one time, then update user_meta with 1 value.

**PHP**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_CounterTrav_update', 'CounterTrav_update' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_CounterTrav_update', 'CounterTrav_update' ); // This lines it's because we are using AJAX on the FrontEnd.

function CounterTrav_update(){
    if(empty($_REQUEST) || !isset($_REQUEST)) {
        ajaxStatus('error', 'Nothing to update.');
    } else {
        try {
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            $CounterTrav_value = $_GET['CounterTrav_value'];
                update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'clickCounterTrav', $CounterTrav_value );
            
            die();
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

If I use

```
var CounterTrav_update = 'total';
```

Then the Sum result is Nan and in Console error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: total is not defined

Comment: this looks like a basic syntax problem with your arrow function, I don't think this has anything to do with WordPress and could be fixed with consistent use of semicolons.

Comment: @TomJNowell, Thank You for your respond and help. Can you please, give me an idea, a guide to where you see my arrow and semicolon errors? i'm new in this world of code. Thanks in advance

Comment: you don't use semi-colons in your arrow function, you should use them, there is only one arrow function in your code ( `thing => { ....` ), this is not a WordPress problem

Comment: Thank You, save may day!